# Button Fetched using ajax does not respond

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a small issue. So i have a `php` page whose content `return` a button using `ajax` such as shown below:

**HTML part:**

```
<a href="#" class="unit_register_button">
    Register
</a>
```

**jQuery part:**

```
$('a.unit_register_button').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    alert('yaay');
});
```

**Problem:**

The button does not respond to the `jQuery`.

I have tried copying the exact line of `html` with the button to the page directly and works perfect when I `click`.

What is the solution and why does the button not work when it is displayed using `ajax`?

Comment: @JoelEtherton That fiddle doesn't demonstrate what the OP's talking about. They load the button with AJAX, but seem to bind the event before that

Comment: @Ian: Reasonable. I glossed over that first sentence apparently. Reading too many questions at once I guess.

Answer (score 3):

you should use [***event delegation***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for that

```
$(document).on("click","a.unit_register_button",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert('yaay');
});
```

Event delegation allows you to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector, whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

Comment: You are missing `e` as function argument

Comment: @Satpal: e is optional.

Comment: @JoelEtherton It's not optional when you **use it**

Comment: @Satpal: I agree with your comment that event delegation is preferred using the `.on`, but this will not solve his problem since his current code works.

Comment: what is the difference between my approach and using event delegation?

Comment: @JohnKariuki `$('a.unit_register_button')` only finds elements at that point in time, and then binds events to **them only**. Event delegation add an event handler to a containing element, which is always there, and can catch children events (since events bubble)

Comment: @JohnKariuki: Event delegation using the `.on` method will allow any future elements that match the identifier to receive this same functionality.

Comment: @Ian: Answer's sample at the time of my comment (relative to the original question) did not contain usage of `e`. Thus, optional.

Comment: @JoelEtherton Ahh I see, I thought I saw all the edits

Answer (score 0):

There is couple ways, one of them is by using `on` function:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.unit_register_button', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Alert message');
});
```

And another is with `delegate` function:

```
$(document).delegate('a.unit_register_button', 'click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Alert message');
});
```

Here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2A3sD/) with working examples.

Hope this helps.